# QString.split missing some empty lines

Tags: qt, split, qstring, qt6, qregularexpression

I'm stuck with this. I am trying to tokenize a multiline QString and count the number of lines.

```cpp
QStringList sentences = m_text.split(QRegularExpression("\n|$"), Qt::SkipEmptyParts);
qDebug() << sentences.size();
```

In spite of the `Qt::SkipEmptyParts` behaviour, I keep getting `1` for a string like this, which should report `5`:

```
Hello\n\n\n\n\n
```

Any Idea of what's wrong.

By the way, if the string has something at the end the count works fine:

```
Hello\n\n\n\n\nBye
```

reports `6` sentences.

Comment: Documentation for [`Qt::SkipEmptyParts`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt.html#SplitBehaviorFlags-enum): *If a field is empty, **don't** include it in the result.* 1 is therefore the expected result. As to the `6` you get in your second test, I believe you have not tested correctly: your string has 5 `\n` that go between 6 strings (if you where to use `Qt::KeepEmptyParts`) but the additional `$` from your regular expression creates 1 last empty string. Had you properly tested, you would have gotten either `2` (with `SkipEmptyParts`) or `7` (with `KeepEmptyParts)` for the result but not `6`.

Comment: My fault! I though I had `Qt::KeepEmptyParts` in my code.  Sorry for the mistake